# In a plsql block all the statements will get rollbacked if any of the statement through error in DML?

Tags: plsql

In a plsql block all the statements will get roll backed if any of the statement through error in DML?

Answer (score 1):

No. You have the power to rollback any specific set of statements when an exception or error comes. You can use

```
SAVEPOINT savepoint_name;
ROLLBACK TO savepoint_name;
```

Create a `SAVEPOINT` before the block till which you want to rollback. `SAVEPOINT` names and marks the current point in the processing of a transaction. Savepoints let you roll back part of a transaction instead of the whole transaction. The number of active savepoints for each session is unlimited.

Example :

```
BEGIN
-- other DML statements
SAVEPOINT do_insert;
   INSERT INTO emp_name VALUES (emp_id, emp_lastname, emp_salary);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      ROLLBACK TO do_insert;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Insert has been rolled back');
END;
```

[SAVEPOINT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABGAAIG)

Answer (score 0):

Not by itself.
With autocommit on the individual sql statement forms a transaction and is committed/rolled back on completion. A block forms an aggregation of statements. If you have one of the statements of a block failing any stateents before (within the block) still have been executed (and committed).

If you want a group of statements to behave transactional you need to use "BEGIN [TRANSACTION]...COMMIT/ROLLBACK" and do proper error handling to your needs.